# Dataframe: Drop columns within a subset when all values in columns are null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing a df that has a variable number of columns whose label starts with T

```
  name  lname  age  T0          T1        T2      T3         othercol
0 john  doe    100  somevalue   34                somevalue
1 jane  doe    99               somevalue         somevalue
2 matt  wright 55   78          somevalue         98
```

I want to remove all columns that have all null values within the columns that start with T.

I am running this:

```
In[1]: T_cols = [column for column in df.columns if column.startswith('T')]
In[2]: df.dropna( axis='columns', how='all', subset=T_cols, inplace=True)
```

I am expecting this result:

```
  name  lname  age  T0          T1          T3         othercol
0 john  doe    100  somevalue   34          somevalue
1 jane  doe    99               somevalue   somevalue
2 matt  wright 55   78          somevalue   98
```

instead i get an exception:

```
  File "/frame.py", line 4285, in dropna
    raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))
KeyError: ['T0', 'T1', 'T2', 'T3']
```

Comment: does `T_cols` run successfully? just to my quick glance you may need an `in` in there

Comment: the `in` is in my original code i just mistakenly removed when i copied it. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('T')]
filtered_cols = df.loc[:, cols].dropna(axis=1).columns
dropped_cols = [col for col in cols if col not in filtered_cols]
new_cols = [col for col in df if col not in dropped_cols]
print(df[new_cols])
```

**Output**:

```
   name   lname  age         T1         T3  othercol
0  john     doe  100         34  somevalue       NaN
1  jane     doe   99  somevalue  somevalue       NaN
2  matt  wright   55  somevalue         98       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), subset refers to a subset of rows if you're dropping columns, and vice versa:

"subset: array-like, optional Labels along other axis to consider, e.g. if you are dropping rows these would be a list of columns to include."

Therefore, you can't drop columns while providing a subset of columns.

Here's a solution that does work:

```
nan = np.NaN
data = {'name': {0: 'john', 1: 'jane', 2: 'matt'},
 'lname': {0: 'doe', 1: 'doe', 2: 'wright'},
 'age': {0: 100, 1: 99, 2: 55},
 'T0': {0: 'somevalue', 1: nan, 2: '78'},
 'T1': {0: '34', 1: 'somevalue', 2: 'somevalue'},
 'T2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan},
 'T3': {0: 'somevalue', 1: 'somevalue', 2: '98'},
 'othercol': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan}}

T_cols = [column for column in df.columns if column.startswith('T')]
other_cols = list(frozenset(df.columns) - frozenset(T_cols))
df_no_t = df[other_cols]
df_t = df[T_cols]
df_t.dropna(axis="columns", how = "all", inplace=True)
pd.concat([df_no_t, df_t], axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
    age lname   name    othercol    T0          T1          T3
0   100 doe     john    NaN         somevalue   34          somevalue
1   99  doe     jane    NaN         NaN         somevalue   somevalue
2   55  wright  matt    NaN         78          somevalue   98
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation but when i test it it is returning this:

       T2    a     c
0  NaN  1.0  None
1  NaN  2.0  None
2  NaN  NaN  None
0  1.0  NaN   NaN
1  2.0  NaN   NaN
2  3.0  NaN   NaN

Comment: @GiuliaL I edited the solution so it would use your date, and also fixed what might have been the issue - added  axis=1 to the concat. Seems to work fine now. The nice thing - it's all vectorized. No for loop.